# unknown conversion type character

Tags: c

I havent ever gotten this before and im not sure how to fix it please help.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int Health;
int Level;
int rnd;
int rnd2;
int counter;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

    counter = 1;
    Health = 100;
    Level = 1;

    while(counter < 2){
        if(Health <= 0){
             break;
        }
        else if(Health > 100){
            Health = 100;
        }
        system("clear");
        printf("Health:%d%\nLevel:%d\n", Health, Level);
        scanf("%d %d", &rnd, &rnd2);
        if(rnd == 1){
            Health = Health - rnd2;
        }
        else if(rnd == 2){
            Level = Level + rnd2;
        }
    }
    system("clear");
    printf("\n\nYou Died!\n\n");
return 0;
}
```

Here's what Terminal said:

Health-Level.c: In function ‘main’:
Health-Level.c:24:3: warning: unknown conversion type character 0xa in format [-Wformat]

Answer (score 2):

Change:

```
"Health:%d%\nLevel:%d\n"
```

to

```
"Health:%d\nLevel:%d\n"
```

Comment: @DarkSun: If your `Health` is intended to be a percentage: `%%` is the format specifier for a literal `%` (and consumes no argument).

Comment: O good thank you alot it was meant to be a percentage that helps alot thanks!